# MapValue use in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a question about using MapValue in Flink because I need to save a map as part of the state, as you know the state needs to be deserializable/serializable, so i extend my class from MapValue because MapValue is an abstract class.

```
public class HashMapValue<K extends Value, V extends Value> extends MapValue<K, V> {
    public HashMapValue() {
        super();
    }
}
```

When i try to use this class, i can’t initiate the class

```
HashMapValue<IntValue, BooleanValue> hashMapValue = new HashMapValue<IntValue, BooleanValue>();
```

the error message is as follows:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.flink.util.ReflectionUtil.getTemplateTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:141)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ReflectionUtil.getSuperTemplateTypes(ReflectionUtil.java:98)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ReflectionUtil.getTemplateType(ReflectionUtil.java:44)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ReflectionUtil.getTemplateType1(ReflectionUtil.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.types.MapValue.<init>(MapValue.java:55)
```

I step into the code and apparently in getTemplateTypes function, it gets K as the parameter instead of IntValue, which I clearly passed in as generic type.

I can’t find online or in the flink source code anything related to MapValue as example. Can anyone help me by pointing out how to use MapValue in Flink?

Comment: the reason why it doesn’t work is because there is a check for K,V type, which expects K, V as class. because the HashMapValue I created is still a generic class, K,V are not class, so the check fails.

Comment: Why do you think you need to extend `MapValue`, versus using it as-is?

Comment: @kkrugler you are right, I changed my implementation and it is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Flink's `MapState` is intended for just this purpose. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/ for an example from the tutorials that are included in the documentation.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear on the initial question, my state has a field which is a map, so in order to serialize/deserialize the state, the field needs to implement Value. So it is not a pure MapState.

But I got it resolved, thank you.

Comment: It could turn out to be dramatically more efficient to split that field out as a separate MapState, rather than having it be a field of a ValueState.

Answer (score 0):

*MapValue* is not for this purpose. Flink state supports Java Map natively, so we can use like *HashMap* as state value directly.